# Fixed / Float view in UIScrollView with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, header, autolayout

In [this technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) Apple states that you can make a subview of UIScrollView fixed / floating by adding constraints to UISCrollView's superview. I tried that but I'm doing something wrong and I can't figure out whats the problem.

> Note that you can make a subview of the scroll view appear to float (not scroll) over the other scrolling content by creating constraints between the view and a view outside the scroll view’s subtree, such as the scroll view’s superview.

That's what I did. I have a UIScrollView already set up and try to add the fixed view to the top of the scrollview like the following:

```c
_testOverlay = [[UIView alloc] init];
_testOverlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
_testOverlay.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.scrollView addSubview:_testOverlay];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_testOverlay]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_testOverlay)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_testOverlay(64)]-(>=0)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_testOverlay)]];
```

However, this does not work, the added view will move along with the scrollview and does not 'float'. Any ideas whats wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> between the view and a **view outside the scroll view’s subtree, such as
>   the scroll view’s superview**.

This part is critical. `self.scrollView` is a superview of `_testOverlay`. So, in `@"|[_testOverlay]|"` vertical bars reference `self.scrollView`. You have to replace this constraint with the constraint between `_testOverlay` and (I suppose) `self.view`. I'm not sure if it's possible with the visual format language, but you certainly can do it with `constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant`. It would go like this (I won't post the whole code, because it's looong):

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:self.view
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                          toItem:_testOverlay
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                          multiplier:1.0
                          constant:0]];
```

Comment: That did the trick! I thought the visual format language superview called by "|" is the view to which I add the constraint. Thank you!

Comment: How would I go about doing this if my `self.view` is `UITableView` and does not have a superview?

Answer (score 0):

Add the overlay view to scroll view's superview, not the scroll view itself.

```
[self.view addSubview:_testOverlay];
```