# Matching widths for Autolayout views in separate hierarchies

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am trying to build a spreadsheet like app which has a scroll view and "floating" headers on the top and left which do not scroll with the rest of the content. I have this implemented in a ScrollView using layoutSubViews to override the frames of the header UIViews, with all the scrolling in a single UIView:

- ScrollView

  - Top Header UIVew
  - Left Header UIVew
  - Content UIView

    - Content

This is all working great, except where the items in the header need to line up with the main content (i.e., "W:cell1==topHeader1", "H:cell1==leftHeader1", etc.). Autolayout won't allow constraints since the items are not in the same hierarchy. How do I keep the widths/heights the same?

Comment: Take a look here for "cleaner" floating headers implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282074/fixed-float-view-in-uiscrollview-with-autolayout

Comment: Jakub, this was the key to my problem. Feel free to make this an answer. :)

Comment: I don't think that pointing to another question is enough for an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better implementing this scenario using `UICollectionView`, if the default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` won't satisfy your requirement subclass it or even create a whole new custom layout.

Such scenario is definitely for `CollectionView`, it will add reusability for the visible cells. So that if you have hundreds of rows/columns, you don't use extra memory.

Comment: UICollectionView looks to abandon AutoLayout more or less entirely. In this scenario I would have to calculate the height and width of each cell to determine the proper height and width for the cells being displayed, and I don't see how AutoLayout can be leveraged to do this since the cells in question may or may not be instantiated at the time. I'm sure it's possible but it's too much for me. :)